# Would the AC from a Sorcerer's Draconic Resistance combine with a Monk's Unarmoured Defence?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, sorcerer, armor-class

Reading from the Player's Handbook. If you pick a Sorcerer with the Draconic Bloodline you get a base AC of 13 (as long as you wear no armour, page 102). If you multi-class that with a Monk you get Unarmoured Defence which allows you to add your Wisdom modifier as well as your Dexterity modifier to your AC (as long as you wear no armour, page 78).

**Would a Sorcerer (dragon bloodline)/Monk have an AC of 13 + Dexterity modifier + Wisdom modifier?**

This seems pretty overpowered for a level 2 character if you get good rolls for your Wisdom and Dexterity (let us not forget to give some love to Charisma though!).

Comment: I'd have sworn we've had this question before though I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Yeah, I did a search and couldn't find anything either, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey You may be thinking of [this related question, Does natural armor stack with unarmored defense?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/does-natural-armor-stack-with-unarmored-defense) which has essentially the same answer as this question.  I think the contexts are different enough that it doesn't count as a duplicate.

Comment: Also related, [How does mage armor intect with unarmored defense?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/how-does-mage-armor-interact-with-unarmored-defense)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### No

Both of these class features give you a different way to calculate your AC and according the page 14 of the PHB:

> Some spells and class features give you a different way to calculate your AC. If you have multiple features that give you different ways to calculate your AC, you choose which one to use.

Comment: That interesting. I agree this rule as written, but I also disagree. Monk feature doesn't mention 10AC plus bonuses, but 10AC is the basic humanoid unarmed base AC isn't it? Not to mention that deacon if blood line adds AC due to passive resistance (tough skin), where as monk feature adds AC from skilled technique. I therefore don't see this as a no-stacking problem because they are different affects. Tough skin plus great skill should be able to stack...now, having said that, I think that would be very over powered. A +3 magic item is Very Rare as a comparison.

Comment: I believe the wording is "your AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier + your Wisdom modifier."

Comment: This sage advice is in agreement with the given answer: http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-january-2016

Comment: @Escoce: It is not a "no stacking" problem at all, because 5E doesn't really have anti-stacking rules like 3E, other than "you cannot stack the exact same thing multiple times". Instead, buffs are carefully designed and worded such that stacking is generally not avaliable. In order to stack two AC effects like those listed, you have to wilfully ignore the rule quoted in this answer *plus* the very clear definitions of the AC abilities, and apply your "common sense" to how you think the rules work. Not only does that fight against the rules, but as you point out it also creates balance issues.

Comment: @all I had some unfortunate autocorrects that I didn't catch. For instance "monk feature DOES mention 10ac plus bonuses" and "draconic bloodlines adds ac due to resistance". I agree with the rules as written, however because of how the AC bonuses are derived I am saying it is counter intuitive that they aren't stackable. I.e.they should be stackable except for a rule to counter the intuitive way to interpret. Not arguing with the rule itself just that it's poorly executed.

Comment: @lithas I looked at that article and it's a good find, and it specifically addresses how to think about ability interactions. He used bark skin and shield for his example, but that's no different than asking about draconic resilience and monks defense because they are a similar analog. One is tough skin while the other is great skill. Why can't you have great skill AND tough skin?

Comment: @Escoce: You can *have* both abilities - the end result is you get the best protection from either the skill or the tough skin. They combine as `max( A, B )` instead of `base + A + B` in the rules. Note that neither of these things has much basis in reality of avoiding being hit or damaged (they protect in too different ways). Instead the rules have been made to fit in the context of other rules. Specifically in 5E, the bounded accuracy design falls apart if you allow a few individuals to stack AC when characters fighting them do not also stack attack bonuses.

Comment: @András Please avoid meaningless edits like that one.

Comment: @András Editing privileges are granted to users to improve the site. Don't use them to make meaningless changes. (If more explanation is needed, please ask on [meta] why it's not OK.)

Answer (score 15):

For additional thought, the Monk ability is not "add your Wisdom bonus to your AC", which would logically stack.

Instead, both abilities specifically define your armor class when not wearing armor (also not using a shield, for Monk).

So you end up with your choice of these two definitions for your unarmored AC.

- AC = 13 + Dex modifier
- AC = 10 + Dex modifier + Wis modifier

Your Sorcerer could multi-class with Barbarian, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Paladin, or Ranger to Pick up Shield Proficiency for an additional +2 to AC.

Additionally Mage Armor also sets AC to 13 + Dex, making it useless for the Draconic Sorcerer to cast it upon himself.