# Does natural armor of Sorcerer stack with lycanthropy?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, armor-class, lycanthropy

My question is whether natural armor of a Sorcerer gained by Draconic Resilience (13 + Dex modifier) does stack with the bonus on natural armor by, e.g., the werebear template ('a +1 bonus to AC while in boar or hybrid form (from natural armor)'), which would make it 13 + Dex modifier + 1 bonus to AC?

To me it seems to be a double application of natural armor but then again if the character would be wearing a half-plate the AC would be 15 + Dex modifier (max 2) + 1 bonus AC, right?

I got a lot of answers from [Does the Sorcerer feature Draconic Resilience work with shields?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49477/does-the-sorcerer-feature-draconic-resilience-work-with-shields/49483#49483) but I cannot filter the answer to my question out of it.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, they should stack, although a DM would be justified in ruling otherwise.

Draconic Resilience (PHB 102)  is a *formula*. A character may only use one formula to derive their Armor Class. In the case you state, they would use either Draconic Resilience *or* the formula for half-plate.

The werebear rules for player character (MM p. 207) refer to a *bonus*. A bonus can apply to any armor class formula, so yes, your calculations are correct, and the PC would have a +1 to whatever AC they would otherwise have.

That is RAW. However, a DM using RAI could certainly decide that the Draconic Resilience is a function of having scaly skin, as described, and that your werebear form would not have that feature. Or they might rule that you become a scaly werebear. Personally, I'd go for the sheer coolness of a draconic werebear...

Comment: +1 for the final sentence alone, though the whole answer is a good one.

Comment: Seems I got it right.
I would also like to have a draconic werebear but I am afraid it will be the "your werebear form would not have that feature" of a scaly skin. Will see...
Thank you very much for your detailed answer!