# How long can you expect to maintain Concentration during combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, statistics, concentration

Every concentration spell has a listed duration in the spell description, like:

> Concentration, up to 1 minute.

Spells that require concentration might end prematurely if the caster takes damage and fails the Constitution save to maintain concentration (Player's Basic Rules, p. 80, italic emphasis mine):

> - **Taking damage.** Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating
>     on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your
>     concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever
>     number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an
>     arrow and a dragon’s breath, *you make a separate saving throw for each
>     source of damage*.

Assuming a combat encounter proceeds in a typical fashion (where the answer must define those assumptions), what is the probabilistic expected duration of a concentration spell?

Comment: I don't know. That whole "encounter proceeds in typical fashion" bit strikes me as unbearably vague. I've voted to close as too broad. I think the fundamental question's (kinda) interesting, so please do ping me in [chat] if you want to talk about its merits and demerits.

Answer (score 10):

## Rounds

This would be the more important metric, but cannot be answered, as it depends on unanswerable things:

- How many times are you attacked per round, and how high is your AC compared to the enemy's hit bonus
- How many spells you are targeted with per round, and how high are your saves compared to the DC, and if those spells deal damage on a save

## Hits

An average can be calculated if we assume you do not get any one damage instance above 21. So **think of this as a best case scenario.**

### Save chance

Without Warcaster, your chance to save is $$\frac{11 + ConSave}{20}$$
As a table:

\begin{array}{r|r}
\text{Con Save} & \text{Success %} \\ \hline
0 &      0.55 \\
1 &      0.6  \\
2 &      0.65 \\
3 &      0.70 \\
4 &      0.75 \\
5 &      0.80 \\
6 &      0.85 \\
7 &      0.90 \\
8 &      0.95 \\
9+ &      1.00 \\
\end{array}

So a 17th level Sorcerer with 14 Con has 95%, and a common, 1st level Wizard with the same Con has 65% to succeed. Let's calculate with the latter one.

### Accumulation

You have a 65% chance to succeed, so 35% chance to fail the 1st Concentration save.
To fail exactly the 2nd save, you have 22.8% ( 0.35 * 0.65 ) chance.
To fail exactly the 3rd save, you have 14.8% ( 0.35 * 0.65 * 0.65 ) chance.
To fail exactly the 10th save, you have 0.7% ( 0.35 * 0.65 ^ 9 ) chance, and so on.

To find the average, you have to multiply these chances with the number of failures they belong to. The sum of the results is the average, so 1 * 0.35 + 2 * 0.228 + 3 * 0.148 and so on, to infinity.

**You can generalize this:**
Chance to fail on the Nth save:
$${FailChance * (1-FailChance)^{N-1}}$$.
The SUM is:
$$\sum {(N * FailChance * (1-FailChance)^{N-1})}$$
This is a tough one to crack, but can be changed into this:
$$\frac {FailChance}{(1-FailChance)} *\sum {(N * (1-FailChance)^N)}$$
WolframAlpha says the SUM can be replaced:
$$\frac {FailChance}{(1-FailChance)} *\frac {1-FailChance}{(FailChance)^2}$$
The end result is surprisingly simple:
$$\frac {1}{FailChance}$$

**Check it with two values**
**Con save +8:** You have a 5% chance to fail, only on a 1.
**1 / 0.05 = 20**, just what you would expect, on average every 20th save will fail.

**Con save +2:** As written above, you have a 35% chance to fail.
**1 / 0.35 = 2.857**. If you start doing the multiplications numerically, the sum of the Product column goes to 2.857 as expected.

\begin{array}{r|r|r}
\text{Fail} & \text{Chance} & \text{Product} \\ \hline
1 &  0.350 &   0.350 \\
2 &  0.228 &   0.455 \\
3 &  0.148 &   0.444 \\
4 &  0.096 &   0.384 \\
5 &  0.062 &   0.312 \\
6 &  0.041 &   0.244 \\
7 &  0.026 &   0.185 \\
8 &  0.017 &   0.137 \\
9 &  0.011 &   0.100 \\
10 &  0.007 &   0.072 \\
\end{array}

### Results

The average number of hits it takes to stop your concentration by Con save:

\begin{array}{r|r}
\text{Con Save} & \text{Hits} \\ \hline
0 &   2.222 \\
1 &   2.500 \\
2 &   2.857 \\
3 &   3.333 \\
4 &   4.000 \\
5 &   5.000 \\
6 &   6.667 \\
7 &  10.000 \\
8 &  20.000 \\
9+ & \infty \\
\end{array}

### Consequences

If you are a frontliner, do not expect your Concentration to last without a proficiency bonus or Warcaster unless you have spectacular AC.

A +9 Con save will give you indefinite Concentration, up to the spell's duration.

Comment: *...you do not get any one damage instance above 21.*   There are ample opportunities to get hit with more damage than that as you go up in level, and if you are hit with a crit.

Comment: That is a crazy amount of math for such an elusive question!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, _"think of this as a best case scenario"_. Some people seem to think you can actually maintain a melee spell for a 100 rounds. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94853/9552

Comment: Re: "Con save +10: You have a 5% chance to fail, as a 1 is always a failure", Natural 1s do not have any special effect on non-death saving throws. If you have at least +9 to con saves, then you will *always* pass concentration checks where the triggering damage is 21 or lower.

Comment: @CTWind, how could I have missed that, I played all wrong

Comment: Your math looks solid, but your conclusion doesn't bring back in things that you were forced to neglect in the math such as AC. A high AC character can indeed expect to maintain concentration for several rounds on the front line due to not taking many hits per round.

Comment: @DerekStucki, a simple CR1/2 Mephit does half damage on a save. So your AC will not protect you from everything.

Comment: @korvinstarmast the bulk of his answer is, indeed, about hits. His conclusion then talks about duration (rounds). That disconnect is the crux of my problem with his conclusion.

Comment: @DerekStucki I see, previous comment voided.