# Spellcasting Multi-class options for level 3 Tiefling Paladin (Oath of Vengance)

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

What spellcaster multiclass options exist for a level 3 tiefling paladin, oath of vengeance, ideally the character should be able to still wear armour and have access to more spells/spell-slots than a normal paladin.

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time you can take the [tour] to find out more about the site. Unfortunately, this question appears to be asking for suggestions which is incompatible with our stack format. As it stands I think it risks being closed for being opinion-based. We do provide a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33707) which are more suitable to this sort of question. Happy gaming!

Comment: Your question does not have a "right" answer, even after the edit. Good is entirely subjective, and this will just result in a bunch of list answers. What might work to get your question not closed is to define clearly what you want the character to do and why pure paladin isn't working for you, but even then, the odds are it'll still be opinion based.

Comment: No spellcasters (except possibly Druid) will take away your ability to wear heavy armor, and all spellcasters will give you more spells and spell slots. You may want to narrow your criteria.

Comment: Are there more narrow criteria you can give us?

Comment: You've asked about multiclassing options and spell slots, all mechanical stuff, then mentioned at the end that pure paladin isn't working "for roleplaying purposes"; to properly answer this question, as it stands, we would need to know what about a pure paladin is affecting your roleplaying intentions to know what kind of spellcaster to suggest, or possibly to frame challenge the question and address the roleplaying directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Charisma based casters...**

Your paladin likely already has a decently high charisma, as many of their attributes scale of charisma. As a result, you will want to multiclass into a charisma-scaling caster, which leaves you with three good options.

**...Sorcerer, Bard or Warlock**

All these classes scale with charisma. You can already wear armor as a paladin, you will not lose this ability if you multiclass into something else. There is however one thing you will need to remember:

*Somatic & Material components*

Many spells require material or somatic components, which makes wearing a shield difficult for your multiclassed paladin. The War Caster feat will bypass this problem for somatic components, but the material component will remain an issue, and you'll either want to not have two occupied hands, or pick only spells that lack a material component.

Comment: Yes Bard seems very appropriate, college of Valor would mean I'd get the extra-attack and synergises well with smiting etc

Comment: A humorous result of your edit: "Leaves you with two good options: Sorcerer, Bard Or Warlock"

Comment: Counting is for silly people! And while that is true, @KorvinStarmast, that would not work for spells from other classes. It only works for paladin spells. (Well, and cleric, who have a similar option.)

Answer (score 1):

## Sorcerer, Warlock or Bard

### Sorcerer

is kind of the default option, with [very good synergies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123247/9552). Quicken Spell (Metamagic) is huge.

### Warlock

gives you even more smites, depending on how many short rests your DM allowes.

### Bard

gives you the best spell options, including Healing Word.

## Levels

You seem to be eager to take a different class, so multiclass at the next opportunity. However, after that I would return to Paladin until I get Aura of Protection. It is *that* good. Also Extra Attack would be sorely missed.